# Sequence spaces $l^p$

Tags: limits, lp-spaces, normed-spaces

I am trying to solve a question as regards $l^p$.

Show that $$\lim_{j\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{j+n}=0$$ for all $(x_1,x_2,...)\in l^2.$

I came up with some idea (which is not guaranteed the right approach). 
Here my idea :

Given $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\frac{1}{N}<\frac{\varepsilon}{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|}$ and $$\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right|\leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left|\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right|\leq \frac{1}{j}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|\leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|<\varepsilon$$ for every $j\geq N.$

The issue is that I don't know how to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|$ is finite. Maybe, I want to use $(x_1,x_2,...)\in l^2$ but I don't know how.

Comment: Unfortunately $\sum|x_n|$ may be  infinite. You could use Cauchy-Schwarz here...

Comment: Well, could you please be more specific where I am supposed to apply the Cauchy-Schwarz?

Comment: Think about it! C-S says $\sum a_nb_n$ is less than or equal to something. There's only one sum of products in sight here...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I think I see now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is clear that for a fixed $n$, $x_n/(j+n)$ goes to zero as $j$ goes to infinity. But it is not clear that we can put the limit inside the sum.

The idea is to use the fact that $(x_n)_n$ belongs to $\ell^2$ to control the remainder: for a fixed $N$, in view of $2\left\lvert ab\right\rvert\leqslant a^2+b^2$, we derive that 
$$
2\left\lvert \sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right\rvert\leqslant 
\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}2\left\lvert \frac{x_n}{j+n}\right\rvert\leqslant 
\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}x_n^2+\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(j+n)^2}\leqslant 
\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}x_n^2+\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}.
$$
Combine this with the convergence $\sum_{n=1}^Nx_n/(j+n)\to 0$ as $j$ goes to infinity, namely, for a fixed $N$
$$\left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right\rvert\leqslant \left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right\rvert+\left\lvert \sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right\rvert\leqslant \left\lvert \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right\rvert+\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}x_n^2+\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}.$$ 
Then take the $\limsup_{j\to +\infty}$.

Comment: Thank you for sharing. It looks good butI have a few questions. From you perspective, it seems to me that  the long inequality you showed gives us that $\left|\sum_{N}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right|$ is finite, am I right? How do we use both inequalities (at the point you say ``combine") to conclude the desired result (I cannot see here). When you say fix $R$, I think you mean $N$, don't you?

Comment: @Nothingone I have edited in order to add more details.

Comment: I think we finally get that $\limsup_{j\rightarrow\infty}\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right|$ is finite. I tsill cannot see how to reach the conclusion that the limit we take tends to $0$. Am I missing something?

Comment: You get more than that: for each $N$, $$\limsup_{j\rightarrow\infty}\left|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x_n}{j+n}\right|\leqslant \sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}x_n^2+\sum_{n=N}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}.$$